# Sort list elements depending on what order anchor targets are within the document

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title may sound confusing I'm trying to break this down to a simple description of the case to hopefully make this clearer.

I have a one page situation with different sections. Each section has its unique ID.

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
  <p>...</p> 
</div>
<div class="section" id="section2">
  <p>...</p> 
</div>
<div class="section" id="section3">
  <p>...</p> 
</div>
...
```

further I want a simple navigation with links to these sections and their IDs.

```
<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

The section's order is interchangeable and I want the navigation to be generated. Is there a way to create list elements on the fly depending on the order of section IDs their href is pointing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try use this code:

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
    <p>...</p>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section2">
    <p>...</p>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section3">
    <p>...</p>
</div>


<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.section').each(function (i, elem) {
            $('.navigation ul').append('<li><a href="#' + $(elem).attr('id') + '">Section ' + i+1 + '</a></li>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you all! Oleg's solution worked immediately and does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the sections by their class, and loop through them using `.each()`. At each `section` you can get it's `id` and construct the relevant list item within the navigation. Lastly, you can add the generated string to the `.navigation` div using `.html()`.

Take a look at a working example below:

```js
let generated = '<ul>';
$('.section').each((i, {id}) => {
  generated += `<li><a href="#${id}">Section ${i+1}</a></li>`;
})
generated += '</ul>';
$('.navigation').html(generated);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" id="section1">
  <p>...</p> 
</div>
<div class="section" id="section2">
  <p>...</p> 
</div>
<div class="section" id="section3">
  <p>...</p> 
</div>


<!-- To generate -->
<div class="navigation">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `.navigation` element using jquery and loop through `.section`, in loop add every anchor tag using `.append()`

```js
var $nav = $('<div class="navigation"><ul></ul></div>');
$(".section").each(function(i){
  $nav.find("ul").append('<li><a href="#'+this.id+'">Section '+(i+1)+'</a></li>');
});
$("body").append($nav);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" id="section1">
  <p>...</p> 
</div>
<div class="section" id="section2">
  <p>...</p> 
</div>
<div class="section" id="section3">
  <p>...</p> 
</div>
```